# How to create a java regular expression pattern that would match a string only at certain positon?

Tags: java, regex

I would like to create a regular expression pattern that would succeed in matching **only if** the pattern string not **followed** by any other string in the test string or input string !  Here is what i tried :

```
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("google.com");//I want to know the right format

      String input1 = "mail.google.com";
      String input2 = "mail.google.com.co.uk";

      Matcher m1 = p.matcher(input1);
      Matcher m2 = p.matcher(input2);

      boolean found1 = m1.find();
      boolean found2 = m2.find();//This should be false because "google.com" is followed by ".co.uk" in input2 string
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `$` to bind the match to the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `google\.com$`. `$` character matches the end of a line.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("google\\.com$");//I want to know the right format

String input2 = "mail.google.com.co.uk";

Matcher m2 = p.matcher(input2);


boolean found2 = m2.find();
System.out.println(found2);
```

Output = `false`

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern should be `google\.com$`.  The `$` character matches the end of a line.  Read about [regex boundary matchers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to match and get the non-matching part as well.

Here is the raw regex pattern as an interactive link to a [great regular expression tool](http://rubular.com/)

[`^(.*)google\.com$`](http://rubular.com/r/mBn04oEjE0)

`^` - match beginning of string
`(.*)` - capture everything in a group up to the next match
google - matches google literal
`\.` - matches the `.` literal has to be escaped with `\`
`com` - matches com literal
`$`  - matches end of string

**Note:** In Java the `\` in the String literal has to be escaped as well! `^(.*)google\\.com$`

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("google\.com$");
```

The dollar sign means it has to occur at the end of the line/string being tested.  Note too that your dot will match any character, so if you want it to match a dot only, you need to escape it.